# External 2TB SATA USB HDD w only 194 GB free of 1.81 TB with only 217 bytes in root drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive

Toshiba External 2 TB, exFAT formatted, USB 3.0 interface connected to a Windows 7 computer.  The external drive has been stored on a shelf for almost 2 years.

When I reconnected it showed 168 GB free of 1.81 TB but when I looked at the root contents there were only about 25 GB of files.  I know about hidden files and the recycle bin so don't think that is the issue.

I got Ran chkdsk and it returned the same results, although it did put a couple dozen zero bytes files in a FOUND folder.  Tried moving files larger than 168 GB to the drive to maybe force the space open but no luck.  I deleted the Recycle bin from the drive in case that was corrupt, no luck. Next I moved everything off the drive. All that's left is the rebuilt recycle bin (29 bytes), FOUND folder (0 bytes), and a System Volume Information with 88 bytes (all according to the properties info in Win Explorer). Properties for the drive still only shows 194 GB of free space out of 1.81 TB. Disk Management shows only 2 partitions, 1 unallocated w 101 MB of unallocated space and the 2nd with 1862.92 GB in a Healthy (Primary Partition). Not sure about the unallocated space but the drive was definitely formatted as exFAT when I purchased it 2nd hand in 2015.

I'd just go ahead and reformat it but I found some notes that say shortly before I put it on the shelf I used it to transfer well over a TB of data from one computer to another onto an external HDD in a dock.  I have not been able to find that target drive and this one did not have that data showing when i opened it.  On the off chance that somehow that data was not thoroughly deleted and still resides on this drive taking up the unreleased free space (I know that is very very unlikely, especially since i wrote nearly 200 GB onto the drive as above) I thought I'd take a shot and see if anyone here:

1. Has any ideas about why all that free space is not showing up (except for all the standard things i've already tried)
2. Anything I might try to see if any of those transferred files are still on this thing in a way I might be able to recover them?

---

I tried to add a screen shot of the drive in Disk Management but it came out too small to be legible.  Suffice it to say the image shows the same information provided above.

Comment: Show us the screenshot in Disk Management for this disk.

Comment: Don't write to or chkdsk etc. a drive you're trying to save data from.

Comment: How are you determining how much space is used and free? There are many posts about why file explorer may not be accurate. I know you said you, “know about hidden files…etc.” But, that doesn’t mention that you understand hidden SYSTEM folders and files and permission issues all which will effect what you see in file explorer. There are many ways to solve this problem - rest assured, the files and folders are there that are taking up space. User folders and system volume information folder are  usually inaccurate if viewing from windows file explorer because of permissions.

Comment: As stated I am determining how much space is used and free by checking the properties for the disk in Explorer (also in windows explorer by selecting 'Computer' and seeing the list of drives in the right window indicating  #.## GB Free of #.## TB.  In this case both show 194 GB free of 1.81 TB.  Is there another way to check used and free space? Is it really possible that there are 1.6 TB of System folders and files?

Comment: There are differing interpretations of "MB", "GB", and "TB". Some parts of Windows display it in decimal, e.g., 1 MB = 1,000,000 bytes, other places as binary, where 1 MB = 2^20, i.e., 1,048,576 bytes. That could be causing you some confusion. Also, disk drive sizes are approximate. Open in diskmgmt.msc or DiskGenius to get an idea.

Comment: I know about the different measurements of MB etc but i fail to see how that coud even come close to making the differences i am describing here?

Comment: How do i show a screen shot on this site?

Comment: diskmgmt.msc shows essentially the same information : 1862.90 GB Capacity and 194.90 GB Free.  CHKDSK also said ### in 49 files.  The root only shows the 23 files in the old FOUND folder, 23 in the new found folder that CHKDSK copied the corrupted files to and 2 files in System Volume Information leaving 1 file unaccounted for.  Isn't system volume info a system file?  If so I presume any other System files would also be visible, no?

Comment: "How do i show a screen shot on this site?" Easiest to edit your OP and add there.

Comment: I essentially have an answer (see below) but wondering if there is any reason to suspect the reliability of the drive once reformatted? If I run CHKDSK and the drive tools after the reformat would that be pretty reliable or should I always be suspicious?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine if you can recover data from this drive, you might as well skip all the trouble shooting and start treating it as a data-loss scenario. For one this means you stop messing with the drive (running chkdsk and that sort of thing).

Ideally this means you clone the drive first to another drive (drive-to-drive) or an image file.

Then as a second step you use a file recovery tool and scan clone or image file for recoverable data.

If you're after one file then may I suggest [DMDE](https://dmde.com) as the demo allows recovery of 4000 files regardless their sizes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and get back with the results

Comment: @warmbeer - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ran RECUVA on the drive and it found the files that I was looking for (I already have many of them so now I have to sort thru and see which were found and recoverable that i don't already have, not a small chore since there are about 5,000 of them in total) some were over written when i tried to fill up the drive. Not great loss. Once I sort them out I'll reformat the drive.